Refactoring CSS pseudo-elements inside nesting
Can :not(:hover) be refactored in  the following CSS, to avoid the repetition?
a.label {
  &[href*="/abc"]:not(:hover),
  &[href*="/def"]:not(:hover),
  /* ... */
  &[href*="/xyz"]:not(:hover) {
    color: #f50;
  }
}


Moving :not(:hover) to the parent is totally fine.
parent-selector {
  &selector1, &selector2 {}
}

is equivalent to
:is(parent-selector)selector1, :is(parent-selector)selector2 {}

In your case, :is(a.label):not(:hover)[href] (original) is equivalent to :is(a.label:not(:hover))[href] (refactored).


a.label:not(:hover) {
  &[href*="/abc"],
  &[href*="/def"] {
    color: #f50;
  }
}
<a class="label" href="./abc">Link1</a>
<a class="label" href="./def">Link2</a>
<a class="label" href="./xxx">Link3</a>



